# Creating a pie chart in excel with single values rather than a table

Tags: excel, charts, ms-office

I am trying to create a pie chart in excel, I want each column in the pie chart to be pulled from a single cell in my excel work book rather than from a table. When I try creating a pie chart it only lets me create it via a series, is there a way that I can make a pie chart without needing to create a table for it to pull from?

That may have been confusing so here is a quick example

I have a work book made up of 3 sheets. (children/adults/and elderly)

The children sheet has a total of 50 that is displayed in the 'total' field
The adult sheet has a total of 40 that is displayed in the 'total' field
The elderly sheet has a total of 22 that is displayed in the 'total' field

I then would want to pull the value of each total with their respective labels and put it in a pie chart.

Is this possible? Or do I need to put the data into a table first, then put it into the chart?

Comment: You need create the table.  Which can of course be done with formulas so it's dynamic

Comment: Have a summary sheet with the table formed with the 3 data items then plot the chart.